# How to create scrollbar in jQuery UI tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using jQuery UI to create 2 tabs. I really only need the first tab (labeled "Queue") to be scrollable, but if all tabs created are vertically scrollable that's fine too.

Note that I do not want or need a horizontal scroll bar.

I've tried placing `overflow: auto;` in various locations in my CSS but I can't seem to find the results I want. My code is on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ctnt/

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

### Update

I need the list of items (inside of `#list-container`) to be scrollable. This whole thing needs to be dynamic, so I can't use any fixed sizes for height. I need the tab content area to consume the remaining space that isn't occupied by the `#button-container` and the container where the list of tabs is stored.

Comment: does overflow-y:scroll work on your list container?

Comment: your `display: table;` is causing your trouble

Comment: the display: table is required to get the layout I want. I can use a real table instead, but I prefer not to. Why is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this CSS may do the work:

```
#list-container {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Edit:**
Without fixed heights:

```
#queue-tab {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#list-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Still need to fix margins... but it seems to work

Comment: I can't use a fixed height here since the body is resizable and children need to resize correspondingly without any manual changes.

Comment: #queue-tab {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#list-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}